# Quick way to invert a fraction

Tags: front-end, formatting, keyboard, customization

Over the years of using Mathematica, I find myself doing something along the lines of rewriting this:

$\frac{[A^-_F]}{[A^-_U] + \frac{[H^+][A^-_U]}{\kappa_1}}$

as this:

$\frac{[A^-_U] + \frac{[H^+][A^-_U]}{\kappa_1}}{[A^-_F]}$

on a constant basis. In other words, just switching the numerator and the denominator of a fraction. Copying and pasting is kind of a drag, especially when you have to do it many times, and Mathematica can be kind of persnickety when it comes to highlighting things. Is there a built in keyboard shortcut that can invert fractions automatically? If not, is there a way for me to build a custom keyboard shortcut in order to do so?

Comment: Perhaps `Ctrl+6` and `-1`(inside the placeholder)?

Comment: The point is to come up with something _more_ convenient than cut-paste. Evaluation would definitely be less.

Comment: Also, with evaluation, if any of the variables have values assigned, the output would be the wrong thing, and it might be scrambled by Mathematica's default simplification routine.

Answer (score 6):

Surely I'm missing something, but...

```
expr = (x - 1) (x - 2)/(x - 3)^2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
1 / expr
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Try menu **Evaluation > Evaluate In Place**

---

### Palette

Since the above is trivial, here is a palette to flip a selected fraction, assuming that it is in the form of a `FractionBox`.  This has the advantage of not evaluating anything, which I suppose could change your expression in an undesired way.

```
Button["Flip Fraction",
 With[{nb = SelectedNotebook[]},
  NotebookWrite[nb,
   Replace[
    NotebookRead @ nb,
    x_FractionBox :> Reverse @ x
   ]
  ]
 ]
]
```

Evaluate the code, then select the Button and choose **Palettes > Generate Palette from Selection**.  You *must* make a Palette; the raw button will not work.

Comment: a nice simple example of button ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Is there any particular reason why you state the button alone would not work? It seems to work just fine here, as I would expect it to.

Comment: Is there any way to assign a keyboard shortcut to a custom button like the one you have above? I use Mathematica mostly as a typesetting program, and I'd like to have a way to invert that doesn't break my flow. Also, what would I add to the button code to get it to automatically select whatever fraction the cursor is currently in (without having to highlight it)?

Comment: @jVincent at least in v7 the window with the fraction loses focus the button in another regular Notebook is clicked, so `SelectedNotebook[]` fails.  Perhaps that has been changed in later versions.

Comment: @tel let me see.

Comment: @tel sorry, I'm still trying to work out *usable* shortcut key behavior.  It's not hard to make a key do the flip, but keeping it from interfering with other things is proving difficult.

Comment: You could wrap it in `CreatePalette` and use `InputNotebook[]` instead, at least in v8 and v9. +1

Comment: I think the first remark, without the palette, is already the fastest  solution. Go to start of the fraction, prepend `1/` to it, press `Control-.` twice to expand the selection until the fraction and `1/` are highlighted, then press `Command-Return` to get the inverted fraction. What could be easier?

Comment: Another advantage of the `1/` method over the `FractionBox` replacement: it simplifies the reciprocal of a fraction like `1/x` to get `x` instead of `x/1`. That's just a special case, but I'd expect in such situations you wouldn't want the `1` in the denominator...